# Moving an asp.net application to membership model

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, membership

I have used asp.net so far to create personal web applications, for example, an application where I maintain to-do tasks in an MS SQL Server database or a customer management and support system. I use the basic authentication via web.config where I can create another user who can look and work with such a database, but then all the data is shared between him and me.

But now I want to convert this application into a membership model where a user signs up and will get to use his own personal list of to-do tasks. I can think of the following approach. Please correct me if I'm wrong on some point or if I have missed something.

Steps:

1. Add a membership user table and use the primary key of this table to access other tables where I will need to add this column, the to-do list in this case.
2. Next, I will need to write the Login, Signup and User management logic to maintain the user table. Here, I was hoping to find some working samples but all searches give me only ASP.NET MVC membership samples. I don't want to use MVC because I am using third-party asp.net components. As far as I know I can not use MVC with those components. Any links to ready made samples similar to MVC but for asp.net?
3. I also want the users to be able to login with their google id, dropbox id, etc. Is this possible while having my own login/signup? How does user table change then? Is the Email Address the only data to link up all these things? For example, if someone logs in with google id, I authenticate using Google oauth 2 API but use the email address as the data to add or locate that user to give him his data tables. I'm confused on how this kind of user table looks where all kinds of logins are possible along with a custom one. Any ideas?

Comment: Refer This
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the exact solution that combines membership with oauth and is built into ASP.NET 4.5. What is more, there is a video that demos it all!

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates

Answer (score 0):

http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/SqlMembershipProvider.aspx
This should help talk you through what you need to do.